# How to cover all branches on this method?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I can't understand how to test this method completely. Eclipse writes "2 of 4 branches are missed".

```
public boolean hasNext() {
        return currIndex < currentSize && aList[currIndex] != null;
    }
```

Below is the unit test that I wrote.

```
@Test
public void hasNextIteratorTest() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Part4 p = new Part4();

    Iterator<String> it = p.iterator();
    p.add("hello");
    p.add("dear");
    p.add("friend");
    p.add("!");
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is this Test supposed to test? As is, it will cover "index < size and item not null" and "index >= size and item not null". So you have to force the branches where item *is* null. All of those branches should have their own Test and you should be using Assertions to provide for useful Messages. And you should isolate the item to test. Meaning: You want to test `hasNext` and it is supposed to return true or false under certain conditions. So you have to create those conditions and then call the method and check the outcome against the expected outcome.

Comment: Hint: if you don't understand all the branches in your code ... make them explicit. SO, if you have `return A && B` ... you can start by turning that into `boolean A = ..; boolean B = ... ; return A &B` and so forth

Answer (score 2):

If you want to cover all branches, you must test all conditions that can happen when your method is called.

```
//1. 
currIndex < currentSize && aList[currIndex] != null;
//2.
currIndex > currentSize && aList[currIndex] != null;
//3.
currIndex < currentSize && aList[currIndex] == null;
//4.
currIndex > currentSize && aList[currIndex] == null;
```

You have to force this results in your @Test method (Or methods).

Comment: Good advice to include would be to add distinct test cases with obvious names which exercise each individually. Also, since it's not included in their example code, adding an assertion example would be useful.